# JavaScript persistent variable

Tags: javascript

I have created a scroll div which works and is fine.  However, my boss now wants to give the client the option of turning of the scrolling feature.  I have done this with a simple boolean variable, the problem being that the results page, which has the scrolling feature, has several pages and if the user clicks on to the next page the scroll feature is enabled again (scroll_thumb="true").  What is the best way to keep a variable available to several pages in your app?  I don't really want to start passing it in the url, or use a hidden form field, is there another way?

This set of pages are running in .net 3.0 framework but are written in classic asp.

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store it in a cookie.

Comment: I did, the app already stored a login credential, and several other pieces of 'stuff' in a cookie, so basically I added to that collection.  Worked really nicely, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Lol, how could I have forgotten about Cookies. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use the framework's (ASP, ASP.NET, or whatever web application framework you're using) state mechanisms to maintain this state across pages.  Session state or view state (or whatever more modern state mechanism they have now) is what should be used.

Rolling your own state maintenance in your own cookie(s) would be a bad way to go. Let the framework help you manage this (it'll likely use it's own cookie, but that should be more or less transparent to you).

Comment: You are right, this is an old classic asp receiving some much needed updating.  It already used cookies so I decided to go with that solution.  Its gonna receive a complete rewrite in the next few months and then I will switch over to this method.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the two common ways of storing persistent data across multiple pages are cookies and hidden form values.  I think the iPhone has reasonable support for cookies, so that's the way I'd go.

Answer (score 0):

use cookies - for a howto in js: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp